# Set UILabel Align top is not working in the cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uilabel, vertical-alignment

I have a problem to implement the text vertical alignment inside a table cell.

What I want to do is based on the length of the text I want to display a message top aligned in side one UILabel inside a cell.

For example if the message is only one line
The text should align top:
[image]

And if there are two rows then it should look like this:

[image]

At the beginning what I can see is like this

[image]

So I have searched the web and what I found is to 
use the

`[label1 sizeToFit];`

But the problem with that is within the table view cell it is not always necessarily called especially when I switched to and from another tab view.

Then I tried to generate the label on the fly by code, but the problem is that let alone the complicated process of setting up the font format I want. I have to manage whether the label has been inserted or not then reuse it every time cellForRowAtIndexpath is called.

And more weirdly, once I select the row. The alignment is switched from the one you see in the first picture to the third one. It also happens when I switched to a different tab view and switch back to the view.

I was wondering if anybody has encountered such issue and have a solution to the problem.

Thank you for your reply in advance.

**Edit:**

@βḧäṙℊặṿῗ, what you said I have tried. It successfully align the label text if there is only one line. My situation is that, since I have multiple tab views. Once I switch back and forth between tabs view. The alignment just restored to centre-vertical alignment again. It also happens when I selected the row. Any idea?

Comment: Did you set     YOUR_LABLE_OBJ.numberOfLines = 0; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
// label will use the number of lines as per content
[myLabel setNumberOfLines:0]; // VERY IMP 
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

**EDIT:**

As you have one extra condition that maximumly display two lines then you need to set `setNumberOfLines`: to 2

```
[myLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
```

Comment: @AashishJoshi Yes. Also read [numberOfLine](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines) and [sizeToFit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit)

Comment: I was tested @βḧäṙℊặṿῗ's answer it was run perfectly u can use this.

Comment: Yes, I have set it to 0. But on switching between the views the labels are not displayed consistently. I was just wondering how the native message app of iphone is implemented.

Comment: I have one extra condition is that maximumly I only display two lines.I need the exactly same behaviour of Iphone's native message app.

Comment: @βḧäṙℊặṿῗ, what you said I have tried. It successfully align the label text if there is only one line. My situation is that, since I have multiple tab views. Once I switch back and forth between tabs view. The alignment just restored to centre-vertical alignment again. It also happens when I selected the row. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Create `UILabel+Extras` and add following methods to this class.

```
- (void)alignTop{
    CGSize fontSize = [self.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font}];
    double finalHeight = fontSize.height * self.numberOfLines;
    double finalWidth = self.frame.size.width;    //expected width of label
    CGRect rect = [self.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(finalWidth, finalHeight) options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font} context:nil];
    CGSize theStringSize = rect.size;
    int newLinesToPad = (finalHeight  - theStringSize.height) / fontSize.height;
    for(int i=0; i< newLinesToPad; i++)
        self.text = [self.text stringByAppendingString:@" \n"];
}
```

Call this method like this..

```
[YOUR_LABEL alignTop];
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's the stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Either You set no of Lines to be 0 like

```
 [yourLabelObject setNumberOfLines:0];
 [yourLabelObject sizeToFit];
```

Or

You can find the height of label at run time depending upon textString length.
Following method will return you the size(height & width) of label for length of text string. 
here width is fixed and only height will change :

```
-  (CGSize) calculateLabelHeightWith:(CGFloat)width text:(NSString*)textString andFont:(UIFont *)txtFont
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(width, 9999);
    CGSize size = [textString sizeWithFont:txtFont
                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}
```

Yo need to calculate frame of label each time when u r doing to set text and set frame of label

I hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Might sound a bit silly but this is my approach: For any field that needs to be top aligned I fill the text up with multiple "\n"s. This causes the text to be automatically top aligned. Pretty much the same as Mehul's method above.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u5q4.png